# Sending Message with Twilio in Swift 4

Tags: swift, twilio, alamofire, message

I am trying to send a message with Twilio API but it is not working. I used Alamofire to send a message. Getting trial account from www.twilio.com and pass related personal parameters to my program. When I run the program, nothing happened. For security reason I used fake numbers for token, SID, phone numbers etc.

**Here is my code:**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire    

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()                
        if let accountSID = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["???????"], let authToken = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["?????"] {                
            let url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/\(accountSID)/Messages"
            let parameters = ["From": "+??????????", "To": "90????????", "Body": "Hello world"]

            Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
                .authenticate(user: accountSID, password: authToken)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)                        
            }                                
            RunLoop.main.run()                
        }        
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you shouldn't be using `authenticate` but instead add those parameters to your request directly in the way defined by the Twillio docs. `authenticate` is only for HTTP authentication and is used to produce a response credential, so unless the server prompts for auth it will not be used.

Also, you don't need that `RunLoop.main.run()`, iOS apps have a run loop automatically.